# How to add additional bands to a TIFF using rioxarray

Tags: rioxarray, xarray

I'm trying to work out how to open a raster, determine the name of the existing band(s), then use that bands value in math to create a new band.

I believe the data is being loaded to a DataArray. I'm outputting that DataArray back to a TIFF, hopping that the extra bands will also be outputted to the TIFF, but they do not appear to be in the resulting tif.

Question 1: Are my assumptions about the math correct? Can I just add an extra band as I would a column in a dataframe? It seems to work?

Question 2: How do I write the bands out in to the same TIFF? My final script will likely require about 20 bands or so, once I work through the math.

```
import xarray as xr
import dask

import multiprocessing
import threading
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, Lock
from dask.utils import SerializableLock

import rioxarray as rio

# Open base raster from X:\base\base_20230116.tif
ras_base = rio.open_rasterio('X://base//base_20230116.tif', chunks={'x': 1000, 'y': 1000}, lock=False)

ras_base['surface_v'] = (ras_base['band'] * 10.1)
ras_base['surface_k'] = (ras_base['surface_v'] / ras_base['band'] + 2)

ras_base.rio.to_raster('D://base//base_20230116_3band_lzw.tif', tiled=True, lock=threading.Lock(), compress='LZW',)
```

The original TIFF:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 79754, x: 57824)>
dask.array<open_rasterio-5453ac0362f7f44b9f393e1a4bd2d754<this-array>, shape=(1, 79754, 57824), dtype=uint16, chunksize=(1, 1000, 1000), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int32 1
  * x            (x) float64 1.536e+07 1.536e+07 1.536e+07 ... 1.71e+07 1.71e+07
  * y            (y) float64 -1.006e+06 -1.006e+06 ... -3.398e+06 -3.398e+06
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:           Area
    RepresentationType:      THEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES:  333517.8561961403
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:      1261
    STATISTICS_MEAN:         658.28229689076
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN:       1101.0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:      0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX:  1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY:  1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:       577.51004856724
    scale_factor:            1.0
    add_offset:              0.0
```

The resulting DataArray after calculation *Note the addition of surface_v and surface_k*

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 79754, x: 57824)>
dask.array<open_rasterio-5453ac0362f7f44b9f393e1a4bd2d754<this-array>, shape=(1, 79754, 57824), dtype=uint16, chunksize=(1, 1000, 1000), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int32 1
  * x            (x) float64 1.536e+07 1.536e+07 1.536e+07 ... 1.71e+07 1.71e+07
  * y            (y) float64 -1.006e+06 -1.006e+06 ... -3.398e+06 -3.398e+06
    spatial_ref  int32 0
    surface_v    float64 111.1
    surface_k    float64 12.1
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:           Area
    RepresentationType:      THEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES:  333517.8561961403
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:      1261
    STATISTICS_MEAN:         658.28229689076
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN:       1101.0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:      0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX:  1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY:  1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:       577.51004856724
    scale_factor:            1.0
    add_offset:              0.0
```

The only thing is, loading the newly written TIFF reveals that there is still only one band.

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].